# Why is there a type mismatch error creating a factory with guava?

Tags: java, guava

I'm trying to create a factory (generating new instances from a String parameter).

I've got a Monster class (the superclass) and Robot1 class (extends Monster).

My factory declares :

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, Class<? extends Monster>> DISPATCHER = ImmutableMap.of("robot1", Robot1.class);
```

But I get :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImmutableMap<String,Class<Robot1>> to ImmutableMap<String,Class<? extends Monster>>
```

Answer (score 6):

It suffices to do

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, Class<? extends Monster>> DISPATCHER = 
   ImmutableMap.of("robot1", (Class<? extends Monster>) Robot1.class);
```

Java tends to assume you want the most specific type possible, even when you don't.  This upcast won't incur any warnings, since it's perfectly safe -- it's just telling the Java compiler that you want the more general type.

Answer (score 2):

This is because, you can have any subtype of `Monster` in place of `Class<? extends Monster>`, which is not actually a `Robot`. So, compiler does not allow the reference with `Class<? extends Monster>` as type parameter, to an intance with more specific type parameter, because that may fail at runtime.

**For E.G: -** `Class<? extends Monster>` can be actually `Class<Zomby>`, which of course `Class<Robot>` cannot be converted to.
This is the reason that, `Class<Robot>` cannot be implicitly cast to `Class<? extends Monster>`

This is similar to the case, where you cannot do: -

```
List<Animal> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

Again, since you can add any type of animal in `dogList`, so, you cannot have more specific type parameter on the RHS

- This check is done at compile time only, and compiler is sure that this may fail at runtime, so, it does not allow for this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `Robot1.class` will return you `Class<Robot>` which can not be cast to `Class<? extends Monster>`

So you will need to add specific cast for such case.

```
ImmutableMap<String, Class<? extends Monster>> DISPATCHER = 
 (ImmutableMap<String, Class<? extends Monster>>)(ImmutableMap<?, ?>)ImmutableMap.of(
                                                        "robot1", Robot1.class);
```

Comment: Why did you add an intermediate cast?

Comment: @RohitJain intermediate cast is need to clear the generics to mark that it can accept any thing and then cast to specific.

Comment: Ok. yeah that is needed. Just tested it on `Number` and `Integer`. That is something I didn't knew. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works fine, without any cast:

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, Class<? extends Monster>> DISPATCHER;

static {
    ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Class<? extends Monster>> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();
    // Monsters types list
    builder.put("robot1", Robot1.class);        

    DISPATCHER = builder.build();
}
```